# Azure Functions , Thumbnail image size is larger than original image

Tags: node.js, image, azure, thumbnails, azure-functions

I have used this [**Background image thumbnail processing with Azure Functions and NodeJS**](http://www.stevenfollis.com/2016/09/24/background-image-processing-with-azure-functions-and-nodejs/) article to create a thumbnail image.An image was created successfully.But the size of image has been increased.How can it be happened ? It must be very small no ? How can I resolve this strange issue ?

***This is the Original Image on the Blob storage***

[image]

[image]

[image]

***After the process (Thumbnail image)***

[image]

[image]

[image]

***This is the Azure function (Node) :***

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = (context, myBlob) => {

    // Read image with Jimp
    Jimp.read(myBlob).then((image) => {

        // Manipulate image
        image
            .resize(200, Jimp.AUTO) 
            .greyscale()
            .getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, (error, stream) => {

                // Check for errors
                if (error) {
                    context.log(`There was an error processing the image.`);
                    context.done(error);
                }
                else {
                    context.log(`Successfully processed the image`);

                    // Bind the stream to the output binding to create a new blob
                    context.done(null, stream);

                }

            });

    });

};
```

Comment: This isn't an Azure Functions issue - it's more of a Jimp issue. You can test it in your local with this image.

Comment: Your content types don't match. Blob storage might store them differently based on the content type.

Comment: Thanks, @AaronChen-MSFT I have found the solution.please see that :)

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I have found the solution.please see that :)

Comment: Yes, but how can we change it? I have put a separate question here: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858321/set-thumbnail-image-content-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this.

> The default quality for JPEGs is 100. You should set this to something
>   lower to gain compression:

You can read more about it here: [**Image is resized down and gets bigger file size**](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/85)

I have to set `.quality(50)` as shown below.This problem is only with the `JPEGs`.

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = (context, myBlob) => {

    // Read image with Jimp
    Jimp.read(myBlob).then((image) => {

        // Manipulate image
        image
            .resize(200, Jimp.AUTO)
            .greyscale()
            .quality(50) // set the quality for JPEGs
            .getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, (error, stream) => {

                // Check for errors
                if (error) {
                    context.log(`There was an error processing the image.`);
                    context.done(error);
                }
                else {
                    context.log(`Successfully processed the image`);
                    // Bind the stream to the output binding to create a new blob
                    context.done(null, stream);

                }

            });

    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, i used sharp and that worked for me. If you need more help, let me know, i will share my complete function code.

```
 const sharp = require('sharp');
 const thumbnailWidth = 250
 module.exports = async (context, myBlob) => {
    
      let thumbBuffer
      const image = await sharp(myBlob)
      image.resize({ width: thumbnailWidth })
      return thumbBuffer = await image.toBuffer()
 }
```