# Set Thumbnail image Content-Type

Tags: node.js, image, azure, thumbnails, azure-functions

I need to set `Content-Type` for the thumbnail image. I have tried as shown below.But it is not working.Still, it stores as a stream.

[image]

**Azure function:**

**index.json**

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = (context, myBlob) => {

    // Read image with Jimp
    Jimp.read(myBlob).then((image) => {

        // Manipulate image
        image
            .resize(200, Jimp.AUTO)
            .greyscale()
            .getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, (error, stream) => {
                if (error) {
                    context.log(`There was an error processing the image.`);
                    context.done(error);
                }
                else {
                    context.log(`Successfully processed the image`);
                    stream.set("Content-Type", Jimp.MIME_JPEG); // here need to set the Content-Type
                    context.done(null, stream);

                }

            });

    });

};
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "project2-photos-original/{name}",
      "connection": "thumbnailfunction_STORAGE",
      "dataType": "binary"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "$return",
      "path": "project2-photos-thumbnail/{name}",
      "connection": "thumbnailfunction_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**I have seen the same implementation like this on NodeJs**

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/my-dynamic-image", function(req, res){
    Jimp.read("lenna.png", function(err, lenna) {
        lenna.resize(64, 64).quality(60).getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, function(err, buffer){
             res.set("Content-Type", Jimp.MIME_JPEG);
             res.send(buffer);
         });
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Question:** Can you tell me how to set `Content-Type` on the Azure function?

p.s. I'm not a Nodejs developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately the blob output binding for node does not support setting a content type.  One option would be to drop the output binding and use the [azure storage sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) natively in your node function which should give you the control you need.

**If using an Http trigger and output binding:**

An express-like 'res' object can be accessed via `content.res`, so instead of `stream.set` you'll want `context.res.set` / `context.res.type`. The `stream` object returned in the `getBuffer` callback is a buffer, not a stream, and has nothing to do with the http response.

One thing to note is that azure functions does not support returning of streams from node yet - you'll need to have the entire buffer (which, luckily, getBuffer appears to return!)

Here is a `getBuffer` callback:

```
function(err, buffer){
    if (err) {
        context.log("There was an error processing the image.");
        context.done(err);
    }
    else {
        context.log("Successfully processed the image");
        // set content type to Jimp.MIME_JPEG
        context.res.type(Jimp.MIME_JPEG)
        // send the raw response (don't apply any content negotiation)
        context.res.raw(buffer);
    }
});
```

Comment: hope `buffer` should be `stream` according to my example no?

Comment: `getBuffer` returns a buffer, not a stream, so I changed naming to minimize confusion.

Comment: can you please show me how to do that with the content on `index.json` file ? please get that content and add your addition into that.Then I'll have a better picture.

Comment: Edited the original answer, I noticed you were using blob bindings instead of http

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support :)